# How to change the AUTOEXTENSIBLE column to YES in table DBA_TEMP_FILES for TEMP TABLESPACE in Amazon ORACLE AWS RDS?

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, tablespace

I have two Oracle DBs, one locally and another in AWS RDS. In Local, I can give the option AUTOEXTEND ON for tablespaces but RDS does not have this option as far as I know.

Also, when I check the DBA_TEMP_FILES in both the DBs, in the local one the autoextensible is YES where as in RDS it is NO.

I want to know if there is anyway we can change this autoextensible to YES in RDS?

I have gone through online links and read through the Amazon AWS documentation but could not find anything related to autoextensible column or AUTOEXTEND replacement.

Comment: I have no experience wtih RDS, but I do know that you DO NOT change the value in DBA_TEMP_FILES.  That is just a view to underlying tables in the data dictionary.  And you do NOT modify those tables unless you want to void your support.  To make a file autoextensible, you have to issue the ALTER DATAFILE ... or ALTER TEMP FILE (as is appropriate).  Does something about AWS prevent you from doing that?  Once you have issued the appropriate MODIFY .. FILE, command, you will see the change reflected in DBA_TEMP_FILES.

Comment: @EdStevens, sorry if my question was not clear.


Yes, I want to make the tempfile or the temp tablespace autoextensible. but the syntax does not work on Oracle RDS

`alter database tempfile resize 10G autoextend on;`

For RDS, to resize we have this syntax:

`exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.resize_temp_tablespace('TEMP','10G');`

but I cannot specify the autoextensible option here. I want to change this autoextensible option to YES from NO

Answer (score -1):

select file_name, AUTOEXTENSIBLE from DBA_TEMP_FILES;

### FILE_NAME

### AUT

/u02/oradata/ORCL/datafile/o1_mf_temp_ho781f7f_.tmp
YES
alter database tempfile '/u02/oradata/ORCL/datafile/o1_mf_temp_ho781f7f_.tmp' autoextend off;
SQL> select file_name, AUTOEXTENSIBLE from DBA_TEMP_FILES;

### FILE_NAME

### AUT

/u02/oradata/ORCL/datafile/o1_mf_temp_ho781f7f_.tmp
NO

Comment: Scott yu, hi, I think the syntax you updated is for oracle and not for Amazon RDS Oracle. this syntax does not work on RDS